# how to parse INI file format in elisp?

Tags: elisp, text-parsing, ini

I want to parse a configuration file in elisp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file.

I haven't find a library that provide this feature, if such library doesn't exist, what's the best way to accomplish this? Are there resources on how to learn to write a parser using elisp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in a buffer and use walk through is using normal movement functions like `forward-line`and check the content of each line with regexp:s using functions like `looking-at` and `match-string`.

I think that this is a good first exercise when it comes to elisp.